# Density function for a multivariate Bernoulli-like distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I'm looking for a distribution to model a vector of $k$ binary random variables, $X_1, \ldots, X_k$.  Suppose I have observed that $\sum_i X_i = n$.  In this case I do not want to treat them as independent Bernoulli random variables.  Instead, I would like something like the multinomial:

$P(X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_k=x_k) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_k; n, p_1, \ldots, p_k) = \frac{n!}{x_1! \cdots x_k!} \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{x_i}$

but instead of the $x_i$ being nonnegative integers, I want them restricted to be either 0 or 1.  I have been trying to see if the [multivariate hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) is appropriate, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: It may be helpful to clarify your distribution a little bit.  What is the distribution before you observe that ∑X_i=n?  Is it iid with Pr[X_i]=p?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking about a _conditional_ distribution _given_ that the sum is $n$?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify distribution over your random vector $\mathbf{X}$. If individual components are binary valued, and you only care about positive distributions, it can be written in the following form

$$P(\mathbf{x})=\exp(\theta_0+\theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 + \ldots + \theta_{12} x_1 x_2 + \ldots +\theta_{1\ldots k}x_1 \cdots x_k)$$

Now the task is determining the distribution of $P(\mathbf{X}|X_1+\ldots+X_k=n)$, this distribution is related to hypergeometric distribution, described in Percy Diaconis "Algebraic algorithms for sampling from conditional distributions" (equations 1.1-1.4)